# Take commas from input field, remove them, and store value with remove comma in different value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input box:

```
<input id='first' placeholder="0" type="text" maxlength="10"autocomplete="off"/>
```

which automatically adds commas when numbers are written:

```
$("#first").keyup(function(event) {

     // skip for arrow keys
     if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

     // format number
     $(this).val(function(index, value) {
          return value
          .replace(/\D/g, "")
          .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
          ;
          });
});
```

I want to store the input value (with commas) in a var and remove the commas with a jquery code, then use the new value of the input (one without commas) as a new variable.

```
var firstValue = Number($('#first').val());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace()` function to remove certain string from string.

```js
$("#first").keyup(function(event) {

     // skip for arrow keys
     if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

     // format number
     $(this).val(function(index, value) {
          return value
          .replace(/\D/g, "")
          .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
          ;
      });
      
      var firstValue = Number($('#first').val().replace(/,/g,''));
      console.log(firstValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='first' placeholder="0" type="text" maxlength="10"autocomplete="off"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.replace(/,/g, '')`

```js
$("#first").keyup(function(event) {

     // skip for arrow keys
     if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

     // format number
     $(this).val(function(index, value) {
          return value
          .replace(/\D/g, "")
          .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
          ;
          });
});

$("#btn").click(function(event) {
var firstValue = Number($('#first').val().replace(/,/g, ''));
console.log(firstValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='first' placeholder="0" type="text" maxlength="10"autocomplete="off"/>
<input type='button' id=btn value=click />
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the `replace` function you can easily do it, it takes a regular expression and a second parameter as the new character, since you want to remove the commas so the 2nd parameter is an empty string.

```js
$("#first").keyup(function(event) {

     // skip for arrow keys
     if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

     // format number
     $(this).val(function(index, value) {
          return value
          .replace(/\D/g, "")
          .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
          ;
          });
});



$("#rmCommas").click(function(){
  var firstValue = $('#first').val();
  var noCommas = firstValue.replace(/,/g , "");
  var asNumber = Number(noCommas);
  alert(asNumber);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id='first' placeholder="0" type="text" maxlength="10"autocomplete="off"/>
<button id="rmCommas">Remove Commas</button>
```